# Private route doesnt redirect to login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have simple app:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <RenderRoutes />
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

Route config as separate object:

```
import { Home } from '../Components/Home';
import { Login } from '../Components/Login';
import { Test } from '../Components/Test';

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    key: 'root',
    component: Home,
    exact: true,
  },
   
  {
    path: '/test',
    key: 'test',
    component: Test,
    exact: true,
  },

  {
    path: '/login',
    key: 'login',
    component: Login,
    exact: true,
  },
]
```

RenderRoutes (routes are imported from route config file):

```
export const RenderRoutes = () => {  
  return (
    <Switch>      
        {routes.map((route) => {          
          return <PrivateRoute key={route.key} {...route}  />
        })}
        <Route component={Error404} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

My PrivateRoute component looks like this:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = false;
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
      return isAuthenticated === true
        ? children
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
    }} />
  )
}
```

But private route renders children all the time no matter isAuthenticated === true or false, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined isAuthenticated to be a constant variable in PrivateRoute component with value as false so it is bound to always render children.

Your `isAuthenticated` value should either be available from props or context or redux store where-ever you store thee authentication status.

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children,isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
      return isAuthenticated === true
        ? children
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
    }} />
  )
}
```

Also note that if your `isAuthenticated` value is populated asynchronously, then you should also have a loading state to account for the delay in calculation or else you will get redirected to login, even if the authentication request is successful.

Comment: I did that for testing private route purposes, i know i must store it in other scope. But its simple comparison, hm. But thanks